# Geolocation behavior

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, geolocation

```
 $('#buttonFindMyLocation'.click(function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      }
      else
      {
        $('.notsupported-browser').removeClass('d-none');
      }
      function showPosition(position) {
        var json_url = './geofindmylocation.php?lat='+position.coords.latitude+'&lng=' + position.coords.longitude;
      }
  })
```

I'll call the `button('#buttonFindMyLocation')` button

How does this work? so let's say I'm going to 2 different locations. Let's name it Location A and Location Z.

I went to location A and open the Browser. I clicked the button and let's say it gives me longitude and latitude = 1.

Refreshed the browser in location A, went to location Z without refreshing the page, if I click the button to find my geolocation does it detect my new location in Location Z or the location from A since I opened the browser there?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: So the NEW as in Current Location, as in whereever the GPS on the device says you are when the call to `getCurrentPosition` is made

Comment: When you call `getCurrentPosition`, it is up to the device to handle all logic. You can request for a "fresh" version by setting an age and timeout: https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/#example-5-forcing-the-user-agent-to-return-a-fresh-cached-position